# Beginner newb here, how to help Tessaract in dot.net do a better job detecting 0 to 0, 5 to S?

Tags: .net, imagemagick, tesseract

I have ImageMagick and Tessaract in dot.net writing in vb.

Im asking for any MagickImage methods yall could think of that could help me with these images that have text on them (they are pdfs but bitmaps on them).

```
image.COlorSpace = ColorSpace.Gray?
image.sharpen?
image.threshhold?
```

what about built in tessaract image manipulations, do those exist with the dot net tessaract engine?

and can I get a link to a good tessaract .datafile? The ones I am using are from 2017, I have the fast and slow version, and the fast seems to be working better.

Thirdly, in MagickImage's image.Resize , the images file size goes from 7mb to 400 .

Last question, does adobe DC PRO license also come with adobe sdk license for dot net ?

Comment: doubling the file size did work with 5 not being false flagged as 'S' , as did usinug fast eng.datafile for tessaract. im looking for a similar workaround for O to 0

Comment: Two many unrelated questions. Please keep your post to a single question. dot net doesn't require a license.